# invoking a Web service Dynamically without creating any Artifacts from Jax-ws web service

Tags: jax-ws

Hi i  have this issue, I am trying to invoke a web service dynamically from my Jax-WS web service.
I tried with glass fish,it is working fine.
but now i shited to apache,and it is giving me the exception

**javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.client.ServiceFactory**

**Note: i added the **jaxrpc.iar****

the code is as shown:

```
enter code here
    ServiceFactory factory = ServiceFactory.newInstance();

  Service service = factory.createService(serviceName);


call = service.createCall();


QName operationName = new QName(TargetNamesSpace,strOperationName,"");

call.setOperationName(operationName);


call.addParameter(
    "arg0",                 // parameter name
    XMLType.XSD_LONG,       // parameter XML type QName
    Long.class,             // parameter Java type class
    ParameterMode.IN);      // parameter mode
//  set the the return type.

call.setReturnType(XMLType.XSD_DOUBLE);

//call.setProperty( Call.OPERATION_STYLE_PROPERTY,"");



call.setProperty(Call.ENCODINGSTYLE_URI_PROPERTY,"");

call.setTargetEndpointAddress(endpoint);


Object[] actualArgs={entityId};

Double computedRating =(Double)call.invoke(operationName,actualArgs);
```

I have one doubt,does the server change make any difference since i am not adding any jar when i tried this on glassfish.

Thanks you.:)

Answer (score 0):

try also add commons-discovery-0.2.jar and axis.jar, can be found as plug in in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Sometime glass fish may collide with tomcat port address thus close netbeans and refresh then open ur project in Tomcat Server or shutdown the port or change the port address for tomcat server.